# Git assumes that all the lines of code have changed

Tags: git

Git assumes that all the lines of code in the files have changed, when only I have changed some lines.
Why this is happening?

Thanks!

---

**Update after feedback** to improve question:
I have changed some code and the line endings from Windows to Unix.

Comment: Please give more information. Was the code commited? Do you see previous changes in `git log` or `git show HEAD`?

Comment: If you could show us the result of a `git diff` of the file in question, that would be useful. And tell us as much info about the state of your git as possible.

Comment: Thanks for I am trying to see this to give more info.

Comment: It appears ^M in every line ending so @MarcinOrlowski had a pretty good guess, even with low info. Had from a search ^M is a changed of line ending also. So is safe to say that this is a line ending think. Thanks all the input.

Comment: Can I just ask what is the best practice in this cases to do a git commit. Should I commit changes when I only change line-ending changes, before commit any other code changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why this is happening?

Most likely you changed either line endings or tabs to spaces (or vice versa).

Comment: The tabs has not the case, but I have changed the line endings from Windows to Unix, so probably this is it. I didn't know that this assumed to be a complete line change. Thanks!

Comment: diffs are per whole lines, so any single change in line affects whole line, no matter how big it is 
. If this answer solves your problem, please [accept it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Comment: Can I just ask what is the best practice in this cases to do a git commit. Should I commit changes when I only change line-ending changes, before commit any other code changes?

Comment: git comes with settings helping to normalize the endings. See: `core.autocrlf` option in [git docs](https://git-scm.com/book/be/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration)

Comment: Thanks! I have look into that and in my case I should config to `core.autocrlf input` (`git config core.autocrlf input`). I also, came a cross a `.gitattributes` to manage line endings for specific files.  [Git docs gitattributes](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) . But I have to say that, at the moment, for me is still not very clear what's the best practice for this line endings thing. But, I will continue to look into that, thanks once again!

Comment: The best practice is simply to have it everywhere the same to aboid LF/CRF poluting your commits. Just make certain setting of `autocrlf` part of repository access policy and ensure every dev is following it. And that's it. It does not matter you want CRLFs in repo or LFs. All it matters is to stick to one of them for good.

Answer (score 0):

You can use side by side difftool, example kdiff3 and compare the file earlier version and changed version.

Git diff the changes in an indentation and the changes what you made. Your question is not  addressing the problem what you face. use git reflog and you will get commands what you did and it might help to understand whats the issue is.

Comment: Thanks for this git commands for understanding the problem. I am trying to see this to give more info.